# NGINX restriction I.P not working

Tags: nginx, rules, ip-restrictions

I have a problem with my configuration, I use nginx/1.10.3, php5-fpm.

this is my default config location :

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
  allow 1.2.3.4; #my ip
  allow 127.0.0.1;
  allow 11.22.33.44; #server ip
  deny all;
}
```

when I try to access 11.22.33.44 i have an 403 Forbidden:

```
2017/03/08 16:30:25 [error] 340#340: *3 access forbidden by rule, client: 1.2.3.4, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "11.22.33.44"
```

Thanks for your help !

Resolve, solution :

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
        allow 127.0.0.1;
        allow 1.2.3.4; #my ip
        deny all;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: @RichardSmith thanks to you reply, I just want to have an access on the location / from my home IP (1.2.3.4) in the exemple ! It's for test my app. (if you have another idea to test my site without anyone can acces it ? i take) ! Else i add a robots.txt to no index the site

Comment: But what is the URI `/` supposed to return? E.g. `index.php` or `index.html`?

Comment: @RichardSmith index.php (i use codeiginiter, with RewriteEngine on apache in localhost.

Comment: Ok, so access rights to `/index.php` will not be controlled by this location block (not entirely anyway).

Comment: Thanks, this give me a way to search.

Answer (score 0):

Checking you .conf file,Make sure that the automatic index is open, or there will be this error

```
 autoindex on;
```